# ViewDoesNotExist django

Tags: django, django-views

I've been working my way through the tutorials and thought that I'd understood the MVC framework.  I have three models, two of which (Guests, Bookings) are populated.  I can call data from Guests no problem.  I tried to call data from Bookings and get ViewDoesNotExist at /bookings Tried booked_dates in module views. Error was: 'module' object has no attribute 'booked_dates'.

My urls are:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
#from views import current_datetime, people, detail, booked_dates

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('views',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'mysite.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^mysite/', include('mysite.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^time/$','current_datetime'),
    url(r'^mariners/$','people'),
    url(r'^mariners/(?P<guest_id>\d+)/$','detail'),
    url(r'^bookings/$','booked_dates'),
)
```

The views are:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext
from guests.models import Guest, Booking, Price
import datetime



def current_datetime(request):
  now = datetime.datetime.now()
  html = "<html><body>It is now %s.</body></html>" % now
  return render_to_response('current_datetime.html', {'current_date': now})

def people(request):
  guests_all = Guest.objects.all().order_by('last_name')
  return render_to_response('guests_all.html', {'guests_all': guests_all})

def detail(request, guest_id):
  g = get_object_or_404(Guest, pk=guest_id)
  return render_to_response('guest_detail.html', {'detail' : g})

def booked_dates(request):
  dates_all = Booking.objects.all().order_by('start_date')
  return render_to_response('bookings.html', {'dates_all' : dates_all})
```

I haven't included the Models, but Booking is the correct class name, and start_date and end_date are correct.

I can't see an exact replica of this problem, and have tried numerous things to correct it, including a simple 'hello world' view, but I get the same error message.

I must be doing something wrong, but can't see what it might be.  I've tried calling the views in a shell, which works.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What version of Django are you using?

Comment: do the other urls work like `mariners` ?

Comment: How have you organized your files? Where is views.py and where is urls.py?

Comment: what about importing from `yourapp.views` not just `views`

Answer (score 1):

try including the app name with the view not just the view function

`url(r'^bookings/$','guests.views.booked_dates'),`

Comment: Just tried that, but the same error message appears.  Also, the 'people' and 'details' views work OK without  guests.views., but thanks anyway.  I'm using Django 2.3.  views.py and urls.py are in 'mysite' which is the higher level directory which also contains the 'guests' folder.

Comment: @user2403107 did you add guests to your installed apps?

Comment: You have to call the url like this `/bookings/`. That should work.

Comment: Thanks @limelights.  I tried that and it changed the error message to 'Page not found 404'.  The 'mariners' page loads perfectly, without a first slash /.

Comment: @dm03514 - thank you!  That did it.  I imported from 'guests.views' and it's fixed the problem.  Many thanks.